# how can i add data into arraylist n number of tymes?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 switch(number){
         case 1 :

            do{

                    Employee e = new Employee();
                    e.show();
                    e.display();
                    ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                    list.add(e);
                    System.out.println("Data is Stored!");
                    System.out.println(list);
                    System.out.println("Add Another Data ? Press Yes=0 or No=1");
                    number = scan3.nextInt();
                }while(number != 1);

                 break;
}
```

data gets added into list only once.i have added do while loop for continous flow but current data nly gets added. need help?
employee is another class where i hav all my user input values. Do i hav to create employee objects everytime i hav to add data into arraylist?

Comment: Create the list once, and an Employee object every time you want a new Employee.

Comment: Agreed. You're creating a new empty list, then adding to it. Result: one-element list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

*before* your loop.

By the way, it's not good declaring the list as ArrayList, because most probably you do not want this dependency. Typical Java idiom is declaring the variables as supertypes, so here as

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

and in Java 7 with its new feature "diamond operator" :) as

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>(); it gives me an error that Type list is not generic,it cannot be parameterised wit argument <Employee>

Comment: sorry didnt work .. same data is getting repeated in array.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Remove above line of code and put it before `do`.